# How do I create a ConstraintLayout with 2 fixed parts and 1 expandable?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

On this topic, I've been going round in circles and have totally confused myself.

I want to create a layout which has 3 components, stacked vertically. The first should be at the top of the screen, and take up however much space it needs (this will increase and decrease as things in it are clicked). The third should be at the bottom and is a fixed size (Google Ads). The one in the middle should take up the remaining space.

I currently have (wrapped in a ConstraintLayout):

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_create_chart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_charts_list"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    ... contents of layout ...
   </ConstraintLayout>
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_charts_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cl_create_chart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/au_adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_charts_list" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/au_adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="..."
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I'm meant to add in some vertical weighting, right? But nothing I try is making any difference - the first bit is floating down the screen so there's blank space above it. Can someone either give me a quick answer or point me to a tutorial that explains how to achieve this?  I've read the Android docs, but can't find anything that includes 'filling the leftover space'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the screen with your three views as you wish, do the following:

**Top view:** width="0dp" (fill screen width); height="wrap_content" (Will let it grow/shrink as needed)

**Middle view:** width="0dp"; height = "0dp" (Fill space within top/bottom constraints.)

**Bottom view:** width="0dp"; height="wrap_content" (Really a fixed size due to nature of the content)

Here is a demo of these concept. I changed a few things around, made a fragment into a generic `View`, for instance, but the concepts are the same.

[image]

**And the XML for this image:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cl_create_chart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_charts_list"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fragment_charts_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/au_adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cl_create_chart" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/au_adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I will also point out that you have "ads" as a namespace prefix when you need an "app" prefix for the constraint layout in the `Adview`.

Comment: Thank you! That's great!